# Panel won't align to the center of screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, panel

For some reason with flexbox it keeps aligning to the left or its doing something extra pulling it that way. I want the panel to be the full width of the screen and I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my code. It is happening in Bootply as well.

http://www.bootply.com/xrIqvTiDHW

Comment: never mind, figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

Needs margin: 0px; to whoever gave this a -1, thanks for being useless.